# Encrypt part of appConfig configSection c#

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, app-config

I have custom config section with Server settings, which includes: username, password and IP of the server; I need to get encrypted config with this type:

```
<ApplicationServerConfiguration>
  <Server UserName="ASDASDASDASDAS [Some encrypted value] ASDASDASF"/>
  <Server Password="ASDASDASDASDAS [Some encrypted value] ASDASDASF"/>
  <Server ServerAddress="192.168.255.255"/> **Not encrypted value!**
</ApplicationServerConfiguration>
```

I can encrypt whole configSection, but not part of it. Who knows how to encrypt just parts of configSection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to encrypt only part of a section. You will have to put the UserName and Password values into a separate section if you want to be able to encrypt them.

Answer (score 4):

You could manually encrypt and decrypt them

```
    private static string EncryptString(string Value)
    {
        string ReturnValue = string.Empty;

        MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Bermuda"));

        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            provider.Key = TDESKey;
            provider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            provider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform Encryptor = provider.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] ByteValue = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Value);

            ReturnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(ByteValue, 0, ByteValue.Length));
        }

        return ReturnValue;
    }
    private static string DecryptString(string EncryptedValue)
    {
        string ReturnValue = string.Empty;

        MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Bermuda"));

        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            provider.Key = TDESKey;
            provider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            provider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = provider.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] ByteValue = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedValue);

            ReturnValue = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(ByteValue, 0, ByteValue.Length));
        }

        return ReturnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `App.config` isn't a good place at all to store security credentials!

Comment: Why not? What about connection string credentials? Where would you recommend storing them?